# How to access ForeignKey data without making extra queries in Wagtail(django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, wagtail

I have the following two classes in my `app.models` and i'm using the wagtail APIs to get the data as json

```
class AuthorMeta(Page):
    author=models.OneToOneField(User)
    city = models.ForeignKey('Cities', related_name='related_author')

class Cities(Page):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

So, when I try `/api/v1/pages/?type=dashboard.AuthorMeta&fields=title,city`, it returns the following data:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "total_count": 1
    },
    "pages": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "meta": {
                "type": "dashboard.AuthorMeta",
                "detail_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/pages/11/"
            },
            "title": "Suneet Choudhary",
            "city": {
                "id": 10,
                "meta": {
                    "type": "dashboard.Cities",
                    "detail_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/pages/10/"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In the city field, it returns the `id` and `meta` of the city. How can I get the name of the city in the response here, without making an extra query? :/

I couldn't find any solution in the [Documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.2/reference/contrib/api/usage.html#the-pages-endpoint). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Django model property to return through the ForeignKey:

```
class AuthorMeta(Page):
    author=models.OneToOneField(User)
    city = models.ForeignKey('Cities', related_name='related_author')
    city_name = property(get_city_name)

    def get_city_name(self):
        return self.city.name
```

Check [Term Property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/glossary/#term-property) to better understand the concept

Comment: This works very well, but what about many-to-one relations. [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498417/how-to-access-manytooneforeignkey-data-without-making-extra-queries-in-wagtaild)

Answer (score 2):

In case you have the foreign key in a Streamfield, e.g. a PageChooserBlock, you can customize the api response by overwriting the `get_api_representation` of a block, as described in the example as provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46028572/6748184):

```
class CustomPageChooserBlock(blocks.PageChooserBlock):
    """ Customize the api response. """

    def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None):
        """ Return the url path instead of the id. """
        return value.url_path
```