# How to access ManyToOneForeignKey data without making extra queries in Wagtail(django)

Tags: python, django, api, wagtail

I have the following two classes in my app.models and i'm using the wagtail APIs to get the data as json

```
class States(Page):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Cities(Page):
    def get_state_name(self):
        return self.state.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.ForeignKey(States, related_name='related_cities' )
    state_name = property(get_state_name)
```

So, when I try /api/v1/pages/?type=dashboard.States&fields=name,related_cities, it returns the following data:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "total_count": 1
    },
    "pages": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "State1",
            "meta": {
                "type": "dashboard.States",
                "detail_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/pages/2601/"
            },
            "related_cities": [
                {
                    "id": 28,
                    "meta": {
                        "type": "dashboard.Cities",
                        "detail_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/pages/28/"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 37,
                    "meta": {
                        "type": "dashboard.Cities",
                        "detail_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/pages/37/"
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In the related_cities field, it returns `id` and `meta` of the cities. How can I get the name of the city in the response here, without making an extra query? :/

I couldn't find any solution in the [Documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.2/reference/contrib/api/usage.html#the-pages-endpoint). Am I missing something?
I want the response something like this

```
            "related_cities": [
                {
                    "id": 28,
                    "name": "SomeCityName1",
                    "meta": {
                        "type": "dashboard.Cities",
                        "detail_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/pages/28/"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 37,
                    "name": "SomeCityName2",
                    "meta": {
                        "type": "dashboard.Cities",
                        "detail_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/pages/37/"
                    }
                },
            ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the name there isn't possible without having to override bits of Wagtail's API module.

But this is something we are working on for version 2 of the API (see: https://github.com/kaedroho/weps/blob/api-fields/draft/005-wagtail-api-fields.rst#nested-objects).

Comment: Thanks Karl. Looking forward to v2. Guess for now, i'll just use [ParentalKey](https://github.com/torchbox/django-modelcluster) ....  `state = ParentalKey(States, related_name='related_cities' )`