# Custom representation of Streamfield in rest API

Tags: api, wagtail

I have a few questions about this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wagtail-developers/Z4oaCIJXYuI

I am building a headless Wagtail, with a React-based frontend, that calls Wagtail API in order to parse JSON and display content. Pretty basic.

I was wondering if it was possible to custom the output of streamfield in rest API. A few examples:

- Get a image URL based on this example from wagtaildemo: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtaildemo/blob/api-tweaks/demo/models.py#L713-L716 (I got it working for single URLs)
- PageChooserBlock: get a field from the targetted page

As I read in the topic linked above, the Wagtail API v1 was not ready for custom representation of Streamfield in it.
Did it change since v2 ? (I didn't notice anything related in changelogs)
If not, does anyone have some tips about how I could achieve such a thing?

I already planned on build a custom image model to get URL by calling `api/v2/images/id`, but I would love to get all these into one JSON response .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of Wagtail 1.9, you can modify the API representation of the Block in the StreamField by overriding the `get_api_representation()` method on the Block.

For your example we can override the method on the ImageChooserBlock itself:

```py
import wagtail 
from rest_framework import serializers

class ImageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = wagtail.images.get_image_model()
        fields = ['title', 'file', 'width', 'height', 'file_size']

class APIImageChooserBlock(ImageChooserBlock):
    def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None):
        return ImageSerializer(context=context).to_representation(value)

@wagtail.snippets.models.register_snippet
class MySnippetForAPI(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    content = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock()),
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('image', APIImageChooserBlock())
    ])
```

Code updated for Wagtail 2.0+

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/b6ee2db6ac8dbf4b47a81f4b2684b7aca8cc2501/wagtail/wagtailcore/blocks/base.py#L244

Answer (score 5):

Adding onto the [very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46028572/1118796) by [probabble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2014660/probabble), you can also use [get_rendition](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12.1/advanced_topics/images/renditions.html?highlight=get_rendition) inside a StreamField block by adding a `SerializerMethodField`:

```py
# serializers.py
# Explicitly importing since models are not loaded when serializers initialized

from wagtail.wagtailimages.models import Image as WagtailImage

class WagtailImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = WagtailImage
        fields = ['title', 'url']

    def get_url(self, obj):
        return obj.get_rendition('fill-300x186|jpegquality-60').url

# blocks.py

from .serializers import WagtailImageSerializer 

class APIImageChooserBlock(ImageChooserBlock):
    def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None):
        return WagtailImageSerializer(context=context).to_representation(value)
```

In this example, we only return the title and url of the image.

Comment: Helped solve my "models not loaded" problem, Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a direct answer to your question but the NHS content store app is solving similar problems and may be a useful reference:

https://github.com/nhsuk/nhsuk-content-store

in particular

https://github.com/nhsuk/nhsuk-content-store/blob/master/api/serializers.py

Comment: This is a great resource. Thank you.