# wagtail get_api_representation() not called

Tags: django-rest-framework, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I am using Streamfields in Wagtail and got the following problem:

I would like to print out the image path instead of the id and followed the instructions here:
[Custom representation of Streamfield in rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956709/custom-representation-of-streamfield-in-rest-api)

But it seems that get_api_representation() is never called in my case.

urls.py

```
router.register(r'page', PageView, basename='page')
```

views.py

```
class PageView(viewsets.mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
   queryset = Page
   serializer_class = PageSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ('title', 'body')
```

models.py

```
class APIImageChooserBlock(ImageChooserBlock):
    def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None):
        if value:
            return {
                'id': value.id,
                'title': value.title,
                'image': value.get_rendition('width-1000').attrs_dict
            }


class ImageTextBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    image = APIImageChooserBlock()
    text = blocks.CharBlock()


class Page(wagtail_models.Page):
    body = StreamField(
        [
            ('MyBlock', ImageTextBlock()),
            ('Newsletter', blocks.StructBlock([
                ('text', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
            ])),
        ]
    )

    content_panels = wagtail_models.Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body', classname="full",  heading=_('Content'))
    ]
```

Can somebody identify the problem here?